# How do I use a microphone on my PC sound card to automatically create a "sweet spot" with excellent frequency response?

Tags: microphone, equalization

Are there any PC sound cards I can buy which support "digital room correction", a feature found on high-end amplifiers, namely the ability to use a microphone to automatically calibrate your sound card to create "sweet spot" that has excellent frequency response?

**Update**

Searched for "Digital Room Correction", and found [DRC: Digital Room Correction](http://drc-fir.sourceforge.net/), software to help do just what I've described. The author of this program is using a TerraTec EWX 24/96 sound card. However, I'm looking for other sound cards with this ability built in as part of the sound card driver.

**Update**

Found [DRC - Digital Room Correction - Wiki](http://www.duffroomcorrection.com/wiki/Main_Page).

**Update**

Found AudioLense from http://www.juicehifi.com/. Plug a microphone into your sound card, and this software corrects for the acoustics of your room. Now to find some more competitors to this software, for comparison.

**Update**

AudioLense recommends "[Professional sound cards or DACs from Lynx or RME](http://www.duffroomcorrection.com/images/f/fb/Audiolense_wiki.pdf)." Its a pity these cards are the price of a Small African Nation.

Comment: Is this for live sound, or for recording?

Comment: For live sound - I'd like something that sounds close to a pure frequency response when I sit in my chair in front of the stereo.

Answer (score 3):

Gravitas,

As a loudspeaker designer let me state, unequivocally, that "dumb" digital room correction with time reversed gazillion tap FIR filters is a terrible idea.

That said, if you want to play with it affordably have a look at [Brute FIR](http://www.duffroomcorrection.com/wiki/Brutefir). You'll need an acceptable quality omni microphone, like the [Audix TM1](http://www.audixusa.com/docs/products/TM1.shtml). There are plenty of reasonably priced usb sound cards.

I'd have to write a small novel to explain why these room correction setups don't work well, but now you can go experiment and learn that for yourself.

If your interested in reading a paper on what sort of things can be addressed properly with this type of processing, I'll refer you to the following [AES paper](http://fulcrum-acoustic.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/improving-loudspeaker-transient-response-with-digital-signal-processing-2005.pdf) by my friend Dave Gunness, formerly of EV, EAW, and now head of engineering at [Fulcrum-Acoustic](http://www.fulcrum-acoustic.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Windows (Vista and 7 at least) has Room Correction. Look at Properties of your speakers under "Sound" in Control Panel.

Not sure this is what you are looking for though. (Just dropped by this site at random.)